# Compare difference in two similar tables without knowing primary key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables *production* and *development*. Both tables are the exact same when it comes to schemas. I am trying to compare the difference between the two tables. I believe the correct way to go about comparing them is as follows:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `production` AS prod
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `non-production` AS nonprod
  WHERE
    nonprod.server = prod.server
    AND nonprod.id = prod.id)
ORDER BY partition_date
```

As here I am finding all records that are in prod that don't exist in nonprod. However with this query I know the primary keys of the table, so I match on them. However, I am working on some tables where I do not know the primary keys for it, how can I go about create the same query for these tables? Would I need to match every single field in a where clause?

Comment: Re "Would I need to match every single field in a where clause?" - yes, unless you know about some lesser field combination about what makes row unique.

Comment: Without a primary key how do you know that row number 7 in the first table is _meant_ to match row number 2 in the second table? You need a primary key. Are you saying there might be a primary key but you don't know what it is? You should first take some steps to determine the primary key. A table without a primary key is not a table and will constantly give you issues in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM table2
```

In this case, the query returns every record in *table1* that are not present in the unique list obtained from *table2*